# How to copy an xml file in one directory to other directory

Tags: java

I want to Copy an xml file from one directory to other directory.
I've used Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING).But i am getting it as a text file.I want it as xml. Please help.

Comment: XML file is text file

Comment: Please add your code (and not just the function's name).

Comment: could you please paste some of your code?

Comment: Source and Destination are in different drives.Is this possible?

Comment: File input = new File("C:\\channels\\AllState\\moretrench\\Test.Allstate.Moretrench_Environmental_Services - Copy.xml");
            
            
             File  destFile1 = new File("D:\\New folder\\AllState\\moretrench\\Test.Allstate.Moretrench_Environmental_Services - Copy.xml");
             Files.copy(input.toPath(), destFile1.toPath(),REPLACE_EXISTING);

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are asking: "I got a text file A.txt in one directory, and I want to represent the content of that file as some B.xml in another directory" ... well, then simple: you will have to

1. parse that text file (identify the information within)
2. decide how to "model" that in an XML like document structure
3. write that as XML

There is simply no generic way of transforming any kind of "text" into XML.

Comment: I just want C:\Folder1\A.xml  to be copied in D:\NewFolder\B.xml

Comment: Sorry, but then your question doesn't make much sense. You got two files, and you already mentioned that you know how to copy them using Java library calls. So *what* is your problem then?!

Comment: I got it.Thank you Ghost..